# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: xampp

my `xampp` not able to find the specified module. It showing an error from D `drive\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlite.dll` and its on changing on every ok button, moreover, my xampp is installed in E drive. What to do now ? Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if you have problem in windows 7 or 8 may you can try for install and replace the xampp.
- if another windows you can restore pint the operating system..

before that, try for backup the data